# how to load a XDocument when the xml is in a string variable?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

How do I load an XDocument when the xml is in a string variable?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`XDocument.Parse(yourvariable)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx

Comment: I think this only available in .NET 3.5 and higher.

Comment: If he's using XDocument over XmlDocument, he's already using .NET 3.5 with probably LINQ to XML!

Comment: Good point. I misread the question.

Comment: No problem, happens to me all the time :)